# Import Enum to Interface breakes Interface

Tags: typescript, enums, interface

I want to import an enum to an interface. (using typescript 2.5) But this will break using the interface in another interface. Here is the example code

---

allEnums.ts

```
export enum ButtonType {
    Top = 1,
    Bottom = 2
}

other enums following ...
```

buttonInterface.d.ts

```
import { ButtonType } from "allEnums";
interface ButtonInterface {
    buttonType: ButtonType
}
```

formInterface.d.ts

```
interface FormInterface { 
    buttos: ButtonInterface[]
}
```

---

Result is an error in formInterface.d.ts

> Cannot find name ButtonInterface

---

What helps is to import the ButtonInterface to the FormInterface like this

```
import { ButtonInterface } from "buttonInterface";
```

But importing Interfaces is not a good solution I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [TypeScript 2.9](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/) you can import a type without importing it's containing module:

```
import("./buttonInterface").ButtonInterface
```

You can use this in your scenario, as long as you are using TypeScript 2.9 or above. You can also give it an alias:

```
type ButtonInterface = import('./buttonInterface').ButtonInterface;

interface FormInterface { 
    buttos: ButtonInterface[]
}
```

Your IDE / text editor might not be up to this, but check by running `tsc` if you see in-editor errors.

Comment: thanks, this works! But this requires still to import the interface. I think this is not a good style. But declaring the the enum as type is also working. I will post the code for this

Answer (score 1):

I think importing the enum as type is cleaner, because one don't want to write code for including interfaces

allEnums.ts

```
export enum ButtonType {
    Top = 1,
    Bottom = 2
}
```

buttonInterface.d.ts

```
type ButtonType = import('allEnums').ButtonType;
interface ButtonInterface {
    buttonType: ButtonType
}
```

formInterface.d.ts

```
interface FormInterface { 
    buttos: ButtonInterface[]
}
```